# How to remove recipient from the PayPal autocomplete list?

Tags: paypal

When I am sending money via PayPal there are some recipients which appear in the autocomplete list. This is the list of emails which appear when I start typing recipients email address.

How can I remove them? I can nowhere find address book or something like that.

**EDIT**

I tried pressing delete button on entry hover, but the entry did not get deleted. Here is the image.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: @DeepakKamat Firefox. Do you have this feature in some other folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove them from your PayPal Address Book. It's a bit unhandy, but you can:

1. Go to **Request Money** in the header
2. Choose **Invoice Settings** in the submenu
3. Select **Address Book** from the left
4. Highlight the recipient you want and **Delete**

[image: PayPal delete recipient]

They'll no longer auto-appear in your Send Money list.

Comment: Paypal's UI has changed and this answer is no longer correct.  I'm searching for the new way & will create a new answer when I find it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Paypal's current UI, the new way to get to the address book is:

1. Select **Summary** in the top navigation bar
2. Scroll down to **Selling Tools** in the left navigation bar and select **Manage invoices**

   [image: Selling tools]
3. Under **Settings** select **Address Book**

   [image: Invoice Settings - Address Book]
4. Select the recipient you want to delete then click [**Delete contact**]

   [image: Address Book]

Answer (score 0):

As of 3/8/17, go to *Tools → Invoicing → Settings → Address Book*, then you can add/delete contacts.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! If you would add a screenshot, or other details that proves that this actually works, the answer would be much better.

Answer (score -1):

When the email id appears in the auto-complete list, hover the email id that appears in the list and press <kbd>DELETE</kbd> button on your keyboard the item should be deleted.

To stop your browser from saving inputs for auto-complete check its documentation.

Comment: Either I am doing something wrong or this does not work. I will update the question with the image

Comment: This only works for browser-saved entries. The PayPal recipients aren't in a browser list so you can't use the normal Shift+Del method.